# How to call Scala method with Map Mutable signature?

Tags: scala, methods, parameters

I have a Scala code:

```
import collection.mutable._

def myMethod(mycollection: Map[A, B]) = {
    ...
  }
```

How do I call this method?

Tried this:

```
myMethod(["test1", "test2"])
```

Got error:
`Identifier expected but 'def' found`

Thanks.

Comment: You can use it like this myMethod(mutable.Map[A, B]) where key of map is of type A and value is of type B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Map` is a data structure that maps a *key* (of some type `K`) to a *value* (of some type `V`). In *Scala*, such a pair can be denoted by the syntax `key -> value`. If your intent is to have a single `String` key "test1" that maps to a `String` value of "test2", then you can do that as follows:

```scala
Map("test1" -> "test2")
```

Your declaration of `myMethod` is invalid: you need to either define actual types for `A` and `B` or make them generic parameters for your method (so that the method is generic):

```scala
// With specific types (assuming both keys and values have String types):
def myMethod(mycollection: Map[String, String]) = //...

// In generic form (allows any key type A, or value type B):
def myMethod[A, B](mycollection: Map[A, B]) = //...
```

Either way, you can then use the result as the argument in a call to your method as follows:

```scala
myMethod(Map("test1" -> "test2"))
```

Some points to note:

- Square brackets are used when defining generic type parameters, or specifying the types used as type parameters.
- Type parameters can be *inferred* from the values supplied. For example `Map("test1" -> "test2")` uses `String` as the type for both the key and the value, and is equivalent to `Map[String, String]("test1" -> "test2")`.
- If you need more than one key/value pair, list them with a comma separator, for example: `Map("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2", "key3" -> "value3")`

I strongly recommend that you read a good book on *Scala*, such as the excellent [*Programming in Scala, 3rd Edition*](https://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_3ed) by Odersky, Spoon & Venners, in order to become familiar with its syntax and standard library.

As a final point, I would strongly recommend that you use the *immutable* version of `Map` whenever possible. If you're not familiar with *functional programming* principles, this will seem unusual at first, but the benefits are huge.